# Code coverage by automation testing

Tags: automated-tests, appium, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am looking for getting test coverage of android app's code.I am using java framework with Appium to do automation test. My agenda is to get test coverage of dev's code by my tests. I am trying with jacoco to do so, but unable to do so uptill now, if anyone having any prior experiences or any step by step links to do so will be  great help.

Comment: So what You exactly need assistance for? Test coverage for dev is done via unit tests, usually written by them (devs). So what are You testing UI tests? Please explain. Tnx

Comment: Yes, My framework includes functional testing of app using UI of it. I want coverage of source code of dev by my tests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133368/jacoco-find-code-coverage-for-external-tests May this would help !

Comment: I got the point, but my BE is deployed in GAE not on tomcat, even if i want to cover BE code, not sure how it will initialize jacocoagent there.